# Conditionally add "using" statements in Roslyn Code Fix

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using the .NET compiler API to write some code analyzers / code fixers in Roslyn.  I want the code fix to transform the following code:

```
string.Format("{0} {1}", A, B)
```

To

```
StringExtensions.SafeJoin(" ", A, B)
```

So far, I have this code:

```
private async Task<Document> UseJoinAsync(Document document, InvocationExpressionSyntax invocationExpr, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var argumentList = invocationExpr.ArgumentList;
    var firstArgument = argumentList.Arguments[1];
    var secondArgument = argumentList.Arguments[2];

    var statement =
        InvocationExpression(
                MemberAccessExpression(
                    SyntaxKind.SimpleMemberAccessExpression,
                    IdentifierName("StringExtensions"), // requires using Trilogy.Miscellaneous
                    IdentifierName("SafeJoin")))
            .WithArgumentList(
                ArgumentList(
                    SeparatedList<ArgumentSyntax>(
                        new SyntaxNodeOrToken[]
                        {
                            Argument(
                                LiteralExpression(
                                    SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
                                    Literal(" "))),
                            Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                            firstArgument,
                            Token(SyntaxKind.CommaToken),
                            secondArgument
                        }))).WithLeadingTrivia(invocationExpr.GetLeadingTrivia()).WithTrailingTrivia(invocationExpr.GetTrailingTrivia())
            .WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);

    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);

    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(invocationExpr, statement);

    var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);

    return newDocument;
}
```

However, I have two outstanding issues:

1) How can I add the required `using Trilogy.Miscellaneous` to the top of the file.

and

2) How can I detect if the required assembly is referenced by my Project. In this case, if my assembly `Trilogy.Common` is not referenced I would either not offer the code fix, or I would propose `string.Join(" ", A, B)` instead of my own `SafeJoin` implementation.

**UPDATE**

I've solved #1 by updating my code as follows...

```
var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(invocationExpr, statement);

// Iterate through our usings to see if we've got what we need...
if (root?.Usings.Any(u => u.Name.ToString() == "Trilogy.Miscellaneous") == false)
{
    // Create and add the using statement...
    var usingStatement = UsingDirective(QualifiedName(IdentifierName("Trilogy"), IdentifierName("Miscellaneous")));
     newRoot = newRoot.AddUsings(usingStatement);
}

var newDocument = document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);

return newDocument;
```

Still hoping for some help with item #2.

Comment: I'm just curious, but the name of SafeJoin kind of implies that string.Join isn't safe? Is that true? If so, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I know `String.Format()` has issues if the amount of args doesn't match the amount of `{#}` in the format string, but if it's actually there with two args, I don't see the issue...

Comment: String.Format() or Join can leave you with extra or trailing whitespace if the arguments are null or empty, or are just whitespace themselves. We don't want that.

var a = "Hello";
var b = "out";
string c = null;

// Returns "Hello out " <- extra space 
var es = string.Join(" ", a, b, null);

// Returns "Hello out " <- extra space
es = string.Join(" ", a, b, string.Empty);

// Returns "Hello out" <- no extra space
var nes = StringExtensions.SafeJoin(" ", a, b, null);

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding some code to the RegisterCodeFixesAsync method.  I feel like the test for my required assembly is a bit of a hack, so I'll accept a better answer to this question if someone posts one.

```
   public sealed override async Task RegisterCodeFixesAsync(CodeFixContext context)
    {
        var root = await context.Document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var diagnostic = context.Diagnostics.First();
        var diagnosticSpan = diagnostic.Location.SourceSpan;

        // Find the type invocation expression identified by the diagnostic.
        var invocationExpr = root.FindToken(
                diagnosticSpan.Start).Parent.AncestorsAndSelf()
            .OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().First();

        // Get the symantec model from the document
        var semanticModel = await context.Document.GetSemanticModelAsync(context.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Check for the assembly we need.  I suspect there is a better way...
        var hasAssembly = semanticModel.Compilation.ExternalReferences.Any(er => er.Properties.Kind == MetadataImageKind.Assembly && er.Display.EndsWith("Trilogy.Common.dll"));

        // Register a code action that will invoke the fix, but only
        // if we have the assembly that we need
        if (hasAssembly)
            context.RegisterCodeFix(
                CodeAction.Create(title, c => UseJoinAsync(
                    context.Document, invocationExpr, c), equivalenceKey: title), diagnostic);
    }
```